# Bundler how to uninstall conflicting dependency

Tags: ruby, macos, vagrant, virtualbox, bundler

I'm trying to execute `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest` on my Mac

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.6
BuildVersion:   16G29
```

but I have an error message after that

> Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins, reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
>   caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
>   issues. The error from Bundler is:
>
> conflicting dependencies winrm-fs (= 1.0.1) and winrm-fs (= 0.2.3)
>   Activated winrm-fs-0.2.3   which does not match conflicting dependency
>   (= 1.0.1)
>
> Conflicting dependency chains:
>       winrm-fs (= 0.2.3), 0.2.3 activated
>
> versus:
>       winrm-fs (= 1.0.1)
>
> Gems matching winrm-fs (= 1.0.1):
>       winrm-fs-1.0.1

So the question is how to resolve this issue with Bundler of how to just install my guest plugin in a safe manner?
Other details

```
vboxmanage --version                                                                                   
5.1.26r117224
Vagrant 1.9.7
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`VAGRANT_DISABLE_STRICT_DEPENDENCY_ENFORCEMENT=1 vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`
resolved the issue. Looks like workaround, but it worked for me and everything seems ok right now.

Comment: Sorry, I am digging up an issue far down in the earth but what does that variable do to fix the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/b90d01377eb41582ad878b7f4f8b1bcb141f05e8/lib/vagrant/shared_helpers.rb#L128 Basically as you can see from error above it requires strict (e.g. pinned ==) version of a library. But this flag allows to install other available versions thus not failing installation

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

Uninstall vagrant **completely** and install it again. But take care, to backup your shares before.

How to uninstall:
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/uninstallation.html

The problem where some old embedded gems inside /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems directory, which I do not know how to update or to select the default version.