# Vagrant 2.0.2 fails to install plugins

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I am running Windows 10 with Vagrant 2.0.2 installed. Just did the update to it and now plugins do not install. It does not matter what the plugin is. Here is an example of the error:

```
C:\Users\Curtis\Projects\local.app.lodgable.com>vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers
Installing the 'vagrant-triggers' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

conflicting dependencies listen (= 3.1.5) and listen (= 3.0.5)
  Activated listen-3.0.5
  which does not match conflicting dependency (= 3.1.5)

  Conflicting dependency chains:
    listen (= 3.0.5), 3.0.5 activated

  versus:
    listen (= 3.1.5)

  Gems matching listen (= 3.1.5):
    listen-3.1.5
```

I have uninstalled Vagrant, restarted, then installed Vagrant, restarted. No joy. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

I have done some research and there are instances of dependency mismatches historically but most chime off with:

> Uninstall Vagrant and then reinstall it

And it seems like all of those reporting the issue get resolution from that or updating Vagrant. I'm going to see about rolling back a version, but wonder if there is something I could do to have the current version work.

EDIT

I've rolled back to version 1.9.8 and have found a new but quite similar error:

```
C:\Users\Curtis>vagrant plugin install vagrant-digitalocean
Installing the 'vagrant-digitalocean' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

conflicting dependencies childprocess (= 0.5.8) and childprocess (= 0.6.3)
  Activated childprocess-0.6.3
  which does not match conflicting dependency (= 0.5.8)

  Conflicting dependency chains:
    childprocess (= 0.6.3), 0.6.3 activated

  versus:
    childprocess (= 0.5.8)

  Gems matching childprocess (= 0.5.8):
    childprocess-0.5.8
```

It seems to be with ruby/gems/bundler but I know next to nothing about that ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

With the assistance of information from locations such as:

[Bundler how to uninstall conflicting dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760176/bundler-how-to-uninstall-conflicting-dependency)
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8785

The workaround is to use the command in this form:

```
VAGRANT_DISABLE_STRICT_DEPENDENCY_ENFORCEMENT=1 vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater
```

since I'm on windows this did not quite work. I had to add it to the deeply nested UI for environment variables

[image]

Then I got some relief. Looks like there is work to be done somewhere for this but at least this works for the meantime.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another (easier?) way to do this on Windows is with the SET command (only lasts for the life of the terminal session:

`> set VAGRANT_DISABLE_STRICT_DEPENDENCY_ENFORCEMENT=1
> vagrant plugin install vagrant-digitalocean
Installing the 'vagrant-digitalocean' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Fetching: multipart-post-2.1.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: faraday-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: vagrant-digitalocean-0.9.3.gem (100%)
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-digitalocean (0.9.3)'!
>`