# How can I install vagrant-winnfsd v1.3.1 plugin with Vagrant 2.2.6?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am on Windows 10 with Vagrant 2.2.6 and Oracle VirtualBox 6.0.14 I am trying to install `vagrant-winnfsd v1.3.1` plugin.

From the command line I execute this command: `vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd`. I get this error:

```
    Failure message received during isntall:

conflicting dependencies openssl (= 2.0.7) and openssl (= 2.0.9)
  Activated openssl-2.0.9
  which does not match conflicting dependency (= 2.0.7)

  Conflicting dependency chains:
    openssl (= 2.0.9), 2.0.9 activated

  versus:
    openssl (= 2.0.7)

  Gems matching openssl (= 2.0.7):
    openssl-2.0.7
```

I have searched online and I found this question/answer
[Bundler how to uninstall conflicting dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760176/bundler-how-to-uninstall-conflicting-dependency)
So I tried the following and it worked:

`VAGRANT_DISABLE_STRICT_DEPENDENCY_ENFORCEMENT=1 vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd`

But this is a work-around and not a solution. 
How can I solve this?

PS: I get the same error when I try to to install any other vagrant plugin, for example: `vagrant-vbguest`. In addition, if the error is not about openssl (= 2.0.7), it's rdoc(= 5.0.0).